# Install Metatrader 5 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: metatrader5, ubuntu-17.04

I try to install Metatrader 5, on Ubuntu 17.04 (64-bit).
I get stuck, and need somebody to help me to solve this problem.
I've installed wine-2.0.1, which is the latest stable version at the moment, and it's for 64-bit. 
Finally, after successfully installing Metatrader 5, on launching the application appears an error window: [terminal64.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6lVT.png), with message:

A debugger has been found running in your system.

Please, unload it from memory and restart your programm.

On wiki.winehq.org, I've found that is needed to install 2 separate versions of wine: 32-bit and 64-bit. I try to do all like in:
https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Biarch_Wine_On_Ubuntu
, but at the stage "Build 64-bit Wine", for: make clean, I got:

make: *** No rule to make target 'clean'.  Stop.

There is a way to really install mt5 on Ubuntu 17.04 ?

Answer (score 5):

Just installed it after suffering a little bit. After seeing many requests from the installer to provide a proxy!

1. **First** install the *latest* **Wine** from the instructions given in its [**website for Ubuntu**](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) (this is the one that will work!)

`sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
 wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
 sudo apt-key add Release.key sudo apt-add-repository

 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`

`sudo apt-get update`

Stable branch:

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable`

2. Configure **Wine** to 32 bits (only your user)

`WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wineboot`

3. Install **Metatrader 5**

`WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 wine start /unix  /path/to/mt5setup.exe`

4. Happiness

[image]

5. Finally to run MetaTrader 5 add the following to your `.bashrc` our `.profile`. And type `metatrader` on your terminal.

`export WINEPREFIX=~/.wine32 
alias metatrader='wine start "C:\program files\metatrader 5\terminal.exe"'`

Thanks to @Kaleshwar Chand

Comment: tq for this solution! i been trying for hours to install metatrader 5 on ubuntu 19.04 x64

Answer (score 1):

I recently installed metatrader5 on ubuntu 17.04, using the instructions found on [mql5 thread](https://www.mql5.com/en/forum/168573)

basically mt5 is 32 bit and your ubuntu is 64 bit so you need to change arch to 32 bit to install/use it properly

enter into terminal

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 wineboot
```

replace user with your username
then install with

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/user/.wine32 wine start /unix  /path/to/mtsetup.exe
```

again replace user with your username

Answer (score 0):

I am running MT5 on Arch,
in my case, a 64bit wineprefix is needed for connect with other apis so...

For install and run it correctly I installed:

`wine`, `wine-mono`, `wine_gecko`, `winetricks`, `playonlinux`

`winetircks` `corefonts`, `winetricks` `winhttp`

**`libgnutls`** allowed to skip the required proxy error

`MT5` was installed throught `playonlinux` on a 64bit `wineprefix`

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps from office winehq at https://wiki.winehq.org/

and find your OS you are using

[Android](https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/android) (WineHQ binary packages for Android)

[Ubuntu](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) (WineHQ binary packages for Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 19.04, and 19.10)

[Debian](https://wiki.winehq.org/Debian) (WineHQ binary packages for Debian Stretch, Buster, and Bullseye)

[Fedora](https://wiki.winehq.org/Fedora) (WineHQ binary packages for Fedora 30 and 31)

[MacOS](https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS) (WineHQ binary packages for macOS 10.8 through 10.14)